# npm run build breaks react router

Tags: reactjs, apache, npm, deployment, webserver

I am currently working on a react project. I am setting it up for deployment, hence building it with the "npm run build" command.

Unfortunately, when I do so and serve the /build contents to an apache webserver (be it on DigitalOcean or on local with XAMPP), all routes are not working and throw a 404 not found error. The homepage works fine though, and so does the project when run through "npm run start command"

I have tried looking for solutions online, but I haven't been able to solve this issue yet.

Comment: Do you have a back-end server set up?

Comment: Yeah, with laravel. It ended up being a .htaccess configuration issue

Answer (score 0):

Want to share this, in case someone bumps into this question in the future:

This is assuming Ubuntu is used as OS:

I've followed certain steps from this [post from Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/4e6lbt/getting_react_routing_to_work_with_apache2) and I can attest this works for making SPAs run in Apache web server with proper routing.

To quote:

1) In the `apache2.conf` located in `etc/apache2/` I turned `AllowOverride` to `All`. I also added Servername localhost in the file. (I somehow skipped this last sentence, but still it worked fine in the end)

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

2) In the `hosts.debian.tmpl` file found in `/etc/cloud/templates` I added `127.0.0.1 <yourdomain.com>` to the file where the other ips of the similiarity are.

```
127.0.0.1 yourdomain.com
```

3) I ran `sudo a2enmod rewrite`. Then I restarted the apache server via `service apache2 restart`. This turns on mod_rewrite.

Lastly inside of my project folder `/var/www/html` , along side my `index.html` file I created a `.htaccess` file and added in the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^.*$ / [L,QSA]
```

End quote

Assuming you've run `npm run build` and then copied all the contents inside the `build` folder to your public directory, this should work.

When I first started web dev, I wasn't really sure I made the VirtualHost config right, so what I usually did was first to make a dummy index.html with, say, Hello World example. When I've confirmed that I'm able to see Hello World in the browser (which means I got the VirtualHost config right), I dump the contents of the `build` folder to where the dummy index.html was.

Hope this helps you now as much as it did for me!